# LINQ order by alphabetical followed by empty string

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of strings:

```
"", "c", "a", "b".
```

I want to use LINQs `orderby` so that the order is alphabetical but with empty strings last. So in the above example the order would be:

```
"a", "b", "c", ""
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
var result = new[] { "a", "c", "", "b", "d", }
    .OrderBy(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace)
    .ThenBy(s => s);

 //Outputs "a", "b", "c", "d", ""
```

Comment: That's cool. You don't even need a lambda for the first ordering, so `source.OrderBy(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace).ThenBy(s => s)`.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively to the existing answers, you could provide an `IComparer<string>` to the `OrderBy` overload:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var letters = new[] {"b", "a", "", "c", null, null, ""};

        var ordered = letters.OrderBy(l => l, new NullOrEmptyStringReducer());

        // Results: "a", "b", "c", "", "", null, null

        Console.Read();
    }
}

class NullOrEmptyStringReducer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        var xNull = x == null;
        var yNull = y == null;

        if (xNull && yNull)
            return 0;

        if (xNull)
            return 1;

        if (yNull)
            return -1;

        var xEmpty = x == "";
        var yEmpty = y == "";

        if (xEmpty && yEmpty)
            return 0;

        if (xEmpty)
            return 1;

        if (yEmpty)
            return -1;

        return string.Compare(x, y);
    }
}
```

<strike>I don't state that this is a *good* example of the `IComparer` implementation (it probably needs to do null checking and handle if both strings are empty), but the point of the answer is to demonstrate the `OrderBy` overload and at the very least works with the question's sample data.</strike>

Due to feedback in the comments and my own curiosity, I've provided a slightly more involved implementation that also takes care of ordering empty strings and null strings relative to each other. Whitespace is not handled.

Still, the point is the ability to provide `IComparer<string>`, not how well you choose to write it :-)

Comment: It's probably inconsequential in this case, but something bothers me where if both `x` and `y` are empty/null it won't return `0`. EDIT: Ahh, good caveat at the end there. +1

Comment: @ChrisSinclair `string.Compare` takes care of it

Comment: @ChrisSinclair You may be correct, but like I state in my disclaimer, the implementation isn't a complete / correct example for production consumption, however it demonstrates the idea with `OrderBy` and at the very least works with the sample array provided. The point of the answer isn't the implementation, it's the `OrderBy` overload.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: I don't think so; I don't think it will ever hit `String.Compare` if both `x` and `y` are empty/null.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair yes `string.Compare` is capable of doing it but in this case it won't reach there

Comment: @ChrisSinclair If you want to provide a better working implementation of `IComparer` I'm happy for my answer to be edited, you raise a good point. I've made an amendment to at least cover your scenario. I've not done any testing with null values.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I have succumbed to peer-pressure.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Sorry for the trouble! :(

Comment: Your `NullOrEmptyStringReducer` class could specify `Comparer<string>` as its base class. Then the method should be an `override` of the `abstract` method inherited. This is just as easy. The advantage is that you get both generic `IComparer<>` and non-generic `IComparer` for free. That's two for the price of one. (Well, even if you need just one.)

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] linqSort = { "", "c","x", "a","" ,"b","z" };
var result = from s in linqSort
             orderby  string.IsNullOrEmpty(s),s
             select s;
```